# Trigger did not execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, database-trigger

I wrote a simple trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_tr 
ON bi_test_tr
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO test (datechange, sum1, sum2, sum3) 
        SELECT 
            GETDATE(), SUM([filed1]), SUM([filed2]), SUM([filed3])
        FROM bi_test_tr 
END
GO
```

Trigger should insert sum of 3 columns (filed1, filed2, filed3) into table `test` with current date.

But when I upload new data set into `bi_test_tr`, nothing was inserted into `test`.

Do you know why?

Comment: Any SQL Server trigger that fails to reference either [inserted or deleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms191300.aspx) sets off warning bells - you're not, in your trigger, making any use of the information about *which* rows in the table has just been changed.

Comment: it's strange because the code from Radu is working....

Comment: what is also strange: when I run code from trigger, it run perfect :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your code with the following:

```
create table bi_test_tr (
    filed1 int,
    filed2 int,
    filed3 int
)
GO

create table test (
    datechange datetime,
    sum1 int, 
    sum2 int, 
    sum3 int
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER test_tr 
ON bi_test_tr
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO test (datechange, sum1, sum2, sum3) 
        SELECT 
            GETDATE(), SUM([filed1]), SUM([filed2]), SUM([filed3])
        FROM bi_test_tr 
END
GO

insert into bi_test_tr values (1,1,1);
insert into bi_test_tr values (2,2,2);
insert into bi_test_tr values (3,3,3);
insert into bi_test_tr values (4,4,4);
insert into bi_test_tr values (5,5,5);

select * from test
```

And got the expected result:

```
2016-05-12 12:03:09.253    1    1   1
2016-05-12 12:03:09.287    3    3   3
2016-05-12 12:03:09.307    6    6   6
2016-05-12 12:03:09.307   10    10  10
2016-05-12 12:03:09.310   15    15  15
```

Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: hi, your code is working....I don't know why what is wrong with my

maybe my select? because into table bi_test_tr I had a col1,col2....col20, and I need to do other select?

Comment: hmm, doesn't seem like that should matter at all; look for simpler things, and double check - is the trigger really deployed? What if you do a PRINT statement within it? Try to take it step by step...

Comment: is deployed: I got exactly the same result as when I run your code.....how to PRINT it ??

Comment: also Im using wizard import data to append it to table -> can it be reason?

Comment: @4est: YES! When you import data through bulk insert, triggers are not fired by default. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187640(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the select first and then the insert. But I'm not sure of that but you should do

```
select getdate(), sum([field1]), sum([field2]), sum([field3]) into var1, var2, var3;
```

And those 3 variables must be declared first. 
Finally you just have to insert those variables.

Again, I'm not sure of that, but you can try :)